# Prime Number Theorem on APs under various conjectures

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

I'm trying to find the best asymptotic expansions for $\pi(x; a, q)$ in various states:

1. Unconditionally we have
   \begin{equation}
   \pi(x; a, q) = \frac{\operatorname{li(x)}}{\phi(q)} + O\left(x \operatorname{exp}\left(-c_1 \sqrt{\log x}\right)\right)
   \end{equation}
   for some constant $c_1$
2. Under GRH we have
   \begin{equation}
   \pi(x; a, q) = \frac{\operatorname{li}(x)}{\phi(q)} +  O\left(x^{1/2 + \epsilon}\right)
   \end{equation}
   for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Do we know any further terms in these asymptotic expansions and are there any other conjectures which give better error terms?

Comment: The first claim (Siegel-Walfisz) is only known under the additional hypothesis that $q \leq \log^A x$ for some fixed $A$ (with $c_1$ depending (ineffectively) on $A$).  A more precise estimate is known if one admits the possibility of a term coming from an exceptional zero; see e.g. Davenport's "Multiplicative number theory".

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I sacrificed accuracy for brevity. I'll have a look at Davenport.

Comment: An error term of roughly $x^\epsilon (x/q)^{1/2}$ for $q \leq x$ is predicted by the Cramer model, and was made explicitly by Montgomery (possibly with some log factor also), see http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=427249

Comment: Under GRH, the error is just $O(\sqrt x\log x)$ (with explicit dependence of the constant on $q$), see e.g. Iwaniec and Kowalski.

Comment: See also page 426 of Montgomery-Vaughan "Multiplicative Number Theory I", particularly Conjecture 13.9.

Comment: One can also adapt the Vinogradov-Korobov prime number theorem to arithmetic progressions provided that one allows for a possible contribution of an exceptional zero.  I'm having trouble tracking down a precise reference for this though.

Answer (score 4):

To the last comment of Terry Tao: For a Vinograodov-Korobov estimate in APs (proved "elementarily" no less), see PRETENTIOUS MULTIPLICATIVE FUNCTIONS AND THE PRIME NUMBER THEOREM FOR ARITHMETIC PROGRESSIONS by DIMITRIS KOUKOULOPOULOS, especially Footnote 2.

http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X12000802